# Output '{' or '}' with string.format(...)

Tags: c#, string

I bet that's an easy question for you, but searching SO or Google with `{` or `}` in the search string doesn't work very well.
So, let's say i wanna output `{Hello World}`, how do i do this using `string.format(...)`?

**Edit:**
looks like this:

```
string hello = "Hello World";
string.format("{0}", '{' + hello + '}');
```

would do the job, but that doesn't look very elegant to me. Is there a way to escape these characters inside the format string?

Comment: Scroll down, your question has already been answered.

Comment: patience .. you get your upvote and right answer soon enough

Comment: Sorry, just thought you hadn't noticed it because the edit came almost 8 minutes after the answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `{{` and `}}`. So your example would be `string.Format("{{Hello World}}");`

Comment: This seems to be similar to the printf convention in C++, using %% if one % is wanted in the output.  Any reason why they didn't use the backslash escape character (which is used in C++ to escape quotes, double quotes, backslashes, ...)?  Just curious.

Comment: @Patrick: It appears that it's because it *already* has a use in that context: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierEscape

Comment: @Patrick: Probably to induce mass confusion and panic. Seriously though, I'm not sure, but you'd have to use multiple backslashes or it'd end up as a character escape ("\{" gives a compiler error because its not a valid escape, "\\" gives a single backslash, so you'd need something like "\\\\{" which is a bit much...)

Comment: @Patrick: the backslash is a compile-time escape char. But the interpretation of { } is at runtime. So while they could have use (double) backslashes that would have been no cleaner or easier than the current choice.

Comment: For the reference of it all :)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx

Comment: Indeed, I think that the difference between compile-time interpretation and run-time interpretation is the real reason why it's different.  Sorry I can't give +2 to you Henk.

Comment: That would be `string.Format("{{{0}}}", hello);`. Oh, my.

Comment: Ah ... ok, i tried "{{0}}" which outputed "{0}", but "{{{0}}}" works great. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem two weeks ago. Resharper solves it automatically.

Putting it as "{" + mystring + "}" and using the "use format string" automatically converted it to string.format("{{{0}}}", mystring).

Comment: nice feature ("3 more to go..")

Answer (score 0):

You might find

```
var hello = "Hello world";
var test = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", "{", hello, "}");
```

easier to read than

```
var test = string.Format("{{{0}}}", hello);
```