# string.format format string containing {

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way for the format string used in a call to string.format to contain a { character that is not used for substring insertion?

For example how could I do this...

```
string.format("my format has this { in it {0}", abc);
```

returning...

```
"my format has this { in it abc"
```

I need to do this as the string I am creating in HTML and will contan a script block of javascript.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Output '{' or '}' with string.format(...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361742/output-or-with-string-format)

Comment: It should be noted that there's an entire section on this in the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yup, you just need to double it:

```
string.Format("my format has this {{ in it {0}", abc);
```

See the "escaping braces" section on the [MSDN page for Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) for more details.

Comment: So, for the OP's use-case he'll need to use `{{` and `}}` throughout his JavaScript. Or pre-process it. Gross.

Comment: I didn't know that.  I thought *everything* was escaped with \

Comment: @Yuck: ... or just don't use format strings to produce Javascript, to be honest...

Answer (score 4):

Double it up to escape it. So "{{" will work properly and will output from the string.format as a single "{"

Answer (score 4):

Use double `{{` brace in your format string.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an article that explains how to escape the curly brace in string.format with a few examples and some good reading.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569608#Question2

EDIT: Adding useful text to accompany link :)

Comment: Please provide some detail in your answers to accompany any links.

Comment: @Yuck, by the time I refreshed the page was full of answers so thought the added text was useless but good call none the less.

Answer (score -2):

it is called escaping. mostly you do a \ in front of the odd char

Comment: "Unrecognized escape sequence."

Comment: Mostly, but not in this case.