# how to add { in String Format c#

Tags: c#, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to escape brackets in a format string in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91362/how-to-escape-brackets-in-a-format-string-in-net)
>   [string.format format string containing {](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402488/string-format-format-string-containing)

I was trying to format string like this,
{Enum.Enum1,"Enum1String"}
I tried this code

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> p in Helper.Dict)
            {
               // file.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} | {1}",p.Key,p.Value));
               file.WriteLine(string.Format("{Enum.{0},\"{1}\"}", p.Value,p.Value));

            }
```

but it doesn not work. How to add { in string format.
I am thinking to use stringbuilder.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From this [MSDN FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569608):

```
string s = String.Format("{{ hello to all }}");
Console.WriteLine(s);    //prints '{ hello to all }'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string t = "1, 2, 3";
string v = String.Format(" foo {{{0}}}", t);
```

See duplicate post here
[How to escape braces (curly brackets) in a format string in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91362/how-to-escape-brackets-in-a-format-string-in-net)

using {{ and }} with result in { and } in String.Format.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, using the `@` operator ensures that the string is represented exactly as it appears in code:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> p in Helper.Dict)
{
       // file.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} | {1}",p.Key,p.Value));
       file.WriteLine(@"{" + string.Format("Enum.{0},\"{1}\"", p.Value,p.Value) + @"}");
}
```

Comment: The @ operator won't change how string.format handles "{" and "}".  Moving them outside of string.format does avoid the problem, yes, but it doesn't actually *solve* it.