# Why do I need double { but a single } in the following string?

Tags: c#

Why do I need double `{` but a single `}` in the following string?

```
static void Main()
{

    Console.Write("a={0}, b={1}, c={{", 1, 2);
    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1, 5)) Console.Write("{0},",i);
    Console.WriteLine("\b}");
}
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [string.format format string containing {](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402488/string-format-format-string-containing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because when you use the templating approach with `string.Format()` or `Console.Write()` with `"{0}"` in strings, the bracket is a special symbol. Therefore, if you want to use an ACTUAL bracket, you need to escape it by doing `"{{"` which will output a single `{`

Comment: Thank you, I understood. The key is "When using {<integer>} templating then { or } must be escaped".

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx, scroll to the section titled **Escaping Braces**

In short, curly braces have special meaning to the string formatter and need to be escaped if you want a literal curly brace in your output string. Similar to escaping double quotes in a string, etc...

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.Write("a={0}, b={1}, c={{", 1, 2);
```

This method you are using is not taking a String, it is using the String.Format() which requires your string to be formatted using curly bracers.

```
Console.Write("a=1, b=2, c={");
```

should work with simple strings without doubling curly braces.